# Async/Await not Waiting for Promise to Resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

It appears that my use of `await` is not behaving as I understood it to.

I thought that an `async` function and the `await` keyword could be used on a call that returns a promise (for instance `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`) and it would pause the function execution (like a generator function) until the promise resolved and then it would continue on with the function.

Even though I am awaiting the call it's returning right away and my console logs are happening out of order. Specifically the console log starting with "reducer" appears in the console before the one starting with "getter", when it should be the other way around/is the opposite of how (I thought) the stack trace should run.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Async helper function getter:

```
const getLocalStream = async () => {
  try {
    const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
    console.log('getter localStream', localStream);
    console.log('about to return')
    return localStream;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

export default getLocalStream;
```

Reducer/store:

```
import getLocalStream from './getLocalStream';

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SEND_CALL': {
      const { id } = action;
      const localStream =  getLocalStream();
      console.log('reducer localStream', localStream);
      const call = state.peer.call(id, localStream);
      return { ...state, call };
    }
    default: 
      return state;
  }
};
```

Console:

```
reducer localStream Promise {<pending>}
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addStream' on 'RTCPeerConnection': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStream'
getter localStream MediaStream {id: "B6Foz1jheGvnMqjiqC4PFoOvUVahF04zigzm", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null, …}
about to return
```

Comment: It *does* pause the execution of `getLocalStream`. It does not pause the execution of its caller (`reducer`) - it just returns a promise to it.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941) can explain why ES uses callbacks, promises and async await syntax. Little spoiler: outside of the async function await doesn't actually wait for anything and async functions immediately return a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [redx-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). Since your reducer has to return a new state you cannot do asynchronous operations in the reducer.

You can do asynchronous operations in middle ware so you can either write middle ware yourself or use redux-thunk.

If you dispatch an action that is a function then thunk will execute that function with the `dispatch` and a `getState` function.

```
//create send call action
const createSendCall = id => 
  async dispatch => {
    const localStream =  await getLocalStream();
    console.log('reducer localStream', localStream);
    const call = state.peer.call(id, localStream);
    dispatch(createDoneSend(call));
  }
//create done send action
const createDoneSend = call => ({
  type:"DONE_SEND",
  call
})

//reducer, SEND_CALL never comes here because it's handled in middle ware
switch (action.type) {
  case 'DONE_SEND': {
    return { ...state, call:action.call };
  }
  default: 
    return state;
```

Thunk will simplify asynchronous middle ware or actions that need to dispatch multiple actions.

How redux works and how the middle ware works is explained [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/redux-middleware/tree/master/basic) it is calling the reducer "application handler function" because I was teaching it as event store, not redux specific.

A reason why redux doesn't accept promises as state and just set the state when it resolves can be found [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/redux-middleware#task-3). When a pending filter request is replaced with a newer request from the user the pending filter will reject, this is what should happen but how would redux know the promise is supposed to reject? So if we have to resolve then how do we tell redux not to set the state when the older pending request resolves? These problems can basically be solved by reducer not returning promises and handle that in the middle ware.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using `peerjs` with this project to handle a P2P video chat via WebRTC. I'm trying to keep the information about the connection and video call in the redux store so I can access it it in different components of my application. It appears the `peerjs` API is strictly callback based (doesn't have a Promise API), will I still be able to use `redux-thunk` in this case?

Comment: @Casey thunk doesn't care about promises or callbacks. You dispatch a function as an acion and thunk will run that function with `dispatch` and `getState`. What you do in the function is up to you, callbacks or promises, no async code but dispatching multiple actions, do nothing at all, whatever is appropriate for that action.  This answer has some code [apiAsPromise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941) that converts a callback type function to a function returning a promise. So does [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48576246/1641941) including a context object (value for this).

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` the call to your `async` function in the reducer.

Right now, you call it, but never wait for it to finish.

Comment: But I am waiting for it to resolve in `getLocalStream`. So it should wait for the the promise to resolve to a regular primitive value and then assign that primitive to `const localStream`, then go on to return localStream which is a primitive. Additionally, I can await in the reducer because it is not an async function and making it an async function brakes the app as store construction needs to be synchronous.

Comment: What the reducer returns is going to be the new state, you now set the new state to a promise of state instead of setting it to state.

Comment: @Casey: You can't escape from asynchrony.  Using `await` makes your own function asynchronous & returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `async/await` in your `reducer` function too, otherwise `getLocalStream()` will just return a `promise` instance.

This is because, according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function),

> When an async function is called, it returns a Promise. When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the returned value.  When the async function throws an exception or some value, the Promise will be rejected with the thrown value.
>
> An async function can contain an await expression, that pauses the
>   execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's
>   resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and
>   returns the resolved value.

```
const reducer = async (state = {}, action) => { //HERE
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SEND_CALL': {
      const { id } = action;
      const localStream =  await getLocalStream(); //HERE
      console.log('reducer localStream', localStream);
      const call = state.peer.call(id, localStream);
      return { ...state, call };
    }
    default: 
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why should `getLocalStream` return a promise? It should wait for the promise returned by `getUserMedia` to resolve before it returns?

Comment: `async` functions always wrap the result in a `Promise.resolve`

Comment: What the reducer returns is going to be the new state, you now set the new state to a promise of state instead of setting it to state.